# Reset of TM1638 display driver

Tags: display, reset, 7segmentdisplay

I am trying to run a TM1638 display off the 6-pin program header of an ATMEGA328P that uses pins PB3, PB4, and PB5.

The screen works fine, but the programmer works only if the screen is not connected.

My understanding is that the RST pin is pulled low when the programmer wants to program the ATmega, but the screen is still active and returning garbage to the programmer.

Is there a simple way I can use a transistor or MOSFET to cut the power to the TM1638 when the RST pin goes LOW in order to disable it when the programmer re-programs the ATmega?

Would I need to cut the high-side power of the TM1638, or would cutting GND do the same thing without any problems?

Is there a better, simpler way to add a RST to a TM1638 display driver?

Comment: Maybe add a ~1K resistor from the DIO pin of the display drive so the programmer can overpower the display response. Just a guess I didn't read the (Chinese) datasheet very carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

If I change the pin order, the screen and programmer both function and I don't have a need to disable the screen during programming.

STB = PB3, CLK = PB5, DATA = PB4

The screen flickers while programing but it programs successfully, and when the ATmega reboots the screen returns to normal.

While not ideal, it is no longer an issue since the ATmega is not reprogramming during normal operation and the screen no longer interferes with reprogramming.

Comment: As these controllers are not compatible with I2C (do not have address) and AVR TWI module can't handle it, it should be driven by software and thus can be connected to any MCU pins that do not interfere with other required functions.